# setJars() method in running Spark SQL app from IDE

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a Spark Sql Application and I want to run it on remote spark cluster from my local machine with my IDE. I know that I should set some option when I create SparkConf Object, smth like this:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
.setMaster("spark://SPARK-MASTER-ADDRESS:7077")
.set("spark.driver.host","my local IP Address")
.setJars(new String[]{"build\\libs\\spark-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"})
.setAppName("APP-NAME");
```

**It's working from IDE and every thing is OK**,

but my questions are:

**1)** Do I need to rebuild the jar file of my app and set it's path to setJars method, every time I change anything? I saw that in some Forums had been said: you will need to build the jar every time you change anything. but It looks a little hard to rebuild app's jar file every time. Is there a better way for that?

**2)** Why is it sometimes not necessary to use setJars method, although I run the program through IDE ? For Example, When I do not use **lambda function** in my code there is no need to setjars function. Just  Assume I have a class of person that have two field: CustomerNo, AccountNo. When I use lamba function in my code like this (personDS is a dataset of person object):

```
personDS.filter(f -> f.getCustomerNo().equals("001")).show();
```

the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

but when I don't use lamba function in my code like this:

```
personDS.filter(col("customerNo").equalTo(001)).show();
```

No Error Occurs. So, Why is this happend? Why I have to use setJars when I use lambda function? When I should use setJars and when not?

Answer (score 2):

So, here i am assuming you are not using `spark-submit` facility and you are running spark program directly from your IDE.

Below is my answer to your first question:

1)  Do I need to rebuild the jar file of my app, every time I change anything? - **YES to deploy your changes you need to build jar each time you make change in code.I use maven for same.**

for second question :

I think that whenever you do any kind of map operation using a lambda which is referring to methods/classes of your project, you need to supply them as an additional jar.

Comment: I didn't understand. If I need to create a jar file every time, What is the use of IDE to run a job?

Comment: creating a jar means you are compiling a code, unless your java changes translated to byte code , you cant find the new changes deployed right?

Comment: IDE gives you flexibility and ease of development also it provides you with multiple tools integration.

Comment: you're right, but when I run a java project, First, it is compiled and then executed. Why does Spark not be able to use .class files that is available along with .java files?

Comment: flexibility and ease of development : This is exactly what I want but this is not the case. It looks a little hard to rebuild app's jar file every time I change anything. Is there a better way for that?

Comment: Well that class file is not built under spark's package structure, as spark has its own structure for jar it is required to be build seperatly because it takes into account many other factors for example depenedent jars to be used in case there are any. For such purposes you can use maven tool for building the jar.

Comment: If this is the case, and there is no other way, It seems that running the job through the IDE does not differ much from its running through spark-submit except in the first case, the output is shown in the IDE and in the second case in the terminal.